# Как получить картинки из всех альбомов и передать их в шаблон jinja?

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

Как вывести по 3 картинки из каждого альбома и передать их в шаблон jinja?

Не могу понять как составить запрос SQLAlchemy.

**Пути:**

```
# routes.py

from app.models import User, Album, Image
from flask import render_template


@app.route('/')
def index():
    albums = Album.query.order_by(Album.timestamp.desc()).all()
    return render_template('index.html', albums=albums)
```

**Модель базы данных:**

```
# models.py

from app import db
from datetime import datetime


class Album(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'albums'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    images = db.relationship('Image', backref='album', lazy='dynamic')


class Image(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'images'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    image_filename = db.Column(db.String)
    image_url = db.Column(db.String)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    album_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('albums.id'))
```

**Шаблон:**

```
# index.html

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block app_content %}
  <h1>Albums</h1>
  {% for album in albums %}
      Id: {{ album.id }}

      ............................

  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Как требуется на этой картинке:

[image: Как требуется получить]

**Дополнения:**

Частично удалось решить проблему, извенив файл шаблона "index.html":

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block app_content %}

  {% for album in albums %}
    <h1>Album ID: {{ album.id}}</h1>
    {% for photo in album.images %}
      {{ photo.image_url }} <br>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Но на странице выводятся все картинки, всех альбомов.
А нужно чтобы выводило только первые 3 картинки у каждогото альбома,
также чтобы альбом не выводился если в нем нет фотографий.

Answer (score 0):

Помогли с решением, вот оно:

```
<!-- index.html -->

{% for album in albums %}
  {% if album %}
    Album ID: {{ album.id}}
    {% for photo in album.images %}
      {% if loop.index < 4 %}
        {{ photo.image_url }}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```